Postgrid Webhook not called laravel
I'd like to set up a webhook for my Laravel application. I created a webhook that triggers on postcard creation and update events, but I'm consistently receiving error codes 419 or 405. Additionally, my Laravel logs don't show any incoming webhook requests, suggesting that my URL is never being called. This means my system isn't capturing the payload or processing the webhook event.
Can you help me troubleshoot this issue?

Did you enter the wrong URL into Postgrid? Just taking a guess. There isn't much information in your question to troubleshoot. Does the webhook work when you test it?

@KIKOSoftware yes i tested url is right .When i hit url in browser it is working but from webhook it is not called also my route type is "any" so it is no  issue regrading route type

The error 405 - Method Not Allowed means that you're trying to make a request to a resource using an unsupported HTTP verb.
For example: postgrid may be trying to create a POST request to your webhook endpoint, but your webhook endpoint only supports the GET method, so you need to check the documentation of postgrid and see the correct HTTP verb to use with your webhook endpoint.
Regarding the error 419 - Page Expired, this error usually happens in Laravel due to a missing CSRF token that's not being sent alongside the request, so what you'll need to do here is to exclude the webhook endpoint from the CSRF check.
The way to do this depends on your Laravel version:
Laravel 11.x: open the bootstrap/app.php file and call the validateCsrfTokens() method within the callback of the withMiddleware() method. This method accepts an array of strings where each string represents a route. These routes will be excluded from the CSRF check, here's how to do it:
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        channels: __DIR__.'/../routes/channels.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->validateCsrfTokens(except: [
            'you-webhook-endpoint/action-name'
        ]);
    })->create();

Laravel 10.x (and older): There's a VerifyCsrfToken middleware within the app/Http/Middleware directory. This middleware has an $except property which you can use to specify endpoints that will be excluded from the CSRF check:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $except = [
        'you-webhook-endpoint/action-name'
    ];
}

Update: actually, there's a simpler solution: if you define the route of the webhook endpoint inside your routes/api.php file then you won't have to manually configure anything related to CSRF as API routes don't have this type of checks.

you are right my issue is solved thank you brother .. one more question when i select payload format JWT from postgrid webhook then in $request->all() i can not get anything but when select json then i can actual data why this is happen can you explain ?

You're welcome!
Regarding your other question, I haven't used postgrid before and I'm not familiar with how they send their data, but I guess that when you choose JWT then the payload of the webhook gets sent within the JWT token itself and you need to decode the token and extract the data, while the JSON payload will cause the webhook's payload to be sent as a JSON string inside the response body.
You may also need to add a secret key to protect your webhook from unauthorized access.

okay i understood thanx for help can you suggest me which language i should learn now node or python ?
